# VB.NET double quoting

Tags: vb.net, quotes

I have a weird double quoting issue when I am expecting only a single set of double quotes.

I am concatenating variables into a single string to build up a powershell command I am going to run via a powershell runspace. I am using String.Format() to format the string, but when I bring in a variable and add ControlChars.Quote around it in the string I  get 2 sets of quotes on each side of the variable. Where as if I dont include quotes at all, I dont get any. Both instances is are incorrect.

```
Dim psCommand As String = New String("")
psCommand = String.Format("New-PublicFolder -Name {0}{1} - {2}{0} -Path \ANZ\NZ\", ControlChars.Quote, CurrentJobProjNumber, CurrentJobProjName)
```

The result I get when running that is: New-PublicFolder -Name ""60412345 - Test Project"" -Path \ANZ\NZ\

I am expecting to get New-PublicFolder -Name "60412345 - Test Project" -Path \ANZ\NZ\

I have tried a number of different ways, all seem to result in the incorrect result above rather than the correct result I am expecting.

```
psCommand = String.Format("New-PublicFolder -Name " & Chr(34) & CurrentJobProjNumber & " - " & CurrentJobProjName & Chr(34) & " -Path \ANZ\NZ\"

psCommand = String.Format("New-PublicFolder -Name {0}{1} - {2}{0} -Path \ANZ\NZ\", Chr(34), CurrentJobProjNumber, CurrentJobProjName)

Dim test As String = New String("")
test = Chr(34) & CurrentJobProjNumber & " - " & CurrentJobProjName & Chr(34)
psCommand = "New-PublicFolder -Name " & test & " -Path \ANZ\NZ"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, for something that seems so simple (and is in C#) I cant work out why in VB.net its such a complicated thing. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks
Bob

Comment: The debugger displays the content of the string in a format that is compatible with the way you'd write it in source code.  Use the Text Visualizer to see the string the way you like it.  Click the spyglass icon.  Not fundamentally different from C#, just different rules.  You'd see backslashes when you debug a C# program.  Same solution, use the Text Visualizer.

Comment: Your first attempt should work as expected.  Check the values of CurrentJobProjNumber  and CurrentJobProjName to make certain that they do not contain your extra quote characters.  The automatic quote completion in newer VS versions can often lead to such issues for those used to entering the end quote themselves, but this usually results in a malformed string entry.  Side note, do yourself a favor and enable Option Strict.  Your usage of `New String("")` is syntactically incorrect (which the IDE would have flagged with Option Strict enabled) in addition to being a waste of coding effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To escape a double quote in vb.net, you simply use two double quotes. I'll give you an example using your last test:

```
    Dim test As String = Nothing
    Dim CurrentJobProjNumber As String = "60412345"
    Dim CurrentJobProjName As String = "Test Project"
    test = """" & CurrentJobProjNumber & " - " & CurrentJobProjName & """"
    Dim psCommand As String = "New-PublicFolder -Name " & test & " -Path \ANZ\NZ"
    MsgBox(psCommand)
```

It definitely looks weird having all those double quotes stacked up like that, but that will get you what you're looking for.